# How do I add a default to a work item field?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I am trying to modify my workitem field

```
<FIELD name="Responsible for test" refname="ResponsibleForTest" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension" />
```

so that it takes the current user as default value, and ideally also warns the user that the value should be set.

I have tried the following

```
<FIELD name="Responsible for test" refname="ResponsibleForTest" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension">
    <DEFAULT from="currentuser"/>
    <VALIDUSER />
    <REQUIRED />
  </FIELD>
```

and several other combinations of just DEFAULT and just REQUIRED. I do not want to copy the current user in, as that would mean it couldn't be set as someone else(am I right?).

After changing the work items, none of the changes seem to have any effect

Comment: "After changing the work items, none of the changes seem to have any effect" - Are you uploading the edited XML back into the project after you've changed it? Setting a default won't prevent any user from changing the value of that field to another user in the project.

Comment: Is this still an issue?